Gradle Kotlin start scripts: how to change +x execute permissions?
I'm slowly trying to switch from Gradle Groovy build files to Kotlin for all my Java apps/projects.  Most things I've figured out, but don't know how to do this / if possible.
My Task for building multiple start scripts in the same project (e.g. a group of runnable samples for an API):
fun createAdditionalScript(name: String, configureStartScripts: CreateStartScripts.() -> Unit) =
  tasks.register<CreateStartScripts>("startScripts$name") {
    configureStartScripts()
    applicationName = name
    outputDir = File(project.layout.buildDirectory.get().asFile, "scripts")
    classpath = tasks.getByName("jar").outputs.files + configurations.runtimeClasspath.get()
    defaultJvmOpts = listOf("-ea")  // enable assertions
  }.also {
    application.applicationDistribution.into("bin") {
        from(it)
        fileMode = 0b000_111_101_101
        duplicatesStrategy = DuplicatesStrategy.EXCLUDE
    }
}

What I'd like to do is: only change the Linux shell start script to be executable (the fileMode line), rather than both the Linux script and Windows batch file.  Is this possible?
